# Testing functions not on the scope in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using Karma test runner and Jasmine. I know how to test functions on the scope.But in case of a situation like this how do I go about it ?

```
listing_app.controller('my_listing_products_list', ['$scope', '$modal',
        function ($scope, $modal) {
      this.someFn = function(a,b){
      //How do i test this function ?
       }

}]);
```

How do I get hold of the this object and the controller context through Jasmine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
describe('my_listing_products_list controller', function(){

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller("my_listing_products_list", {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('should exist', function($controller){
    expect(ctrl.someFn()).toBe('whatever the function returns')
  });
})
```