# Testing functions not on the scope AND with no "this" keyword in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

This question is a piggy-back if you will, off of a previous S.O. question linked here: [Testing functions not on the scope in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910445/testing-functions-not-on-the-scope-in-the-controller)

I have a similar problem that I have been dealing with but cannot find an answer to. I am also using Karma test runner and Jasmine. I also know how to test functions on the scope and with the "this" keyword. I cannot however find a way to unit test a function that is not in the scope and not connected to the "this" keyword.

The following function 'foo' is an example of a function that would run when the app loads. Inside of this function I have some logic that I would like to unit test.

```
controller('myController',function(){

    //calls function foo once the page loads
    foo();

    function foo(){
        //completes tasks on load
    };


});
```

Jasmine/Karma does not recognize my reference to 'foo', therefore I cannot unit test any logic within. I was told that these types of functions in AngularJS are NOT ani-patterns. Any advice on how I could do unit test them?

Comment: Test what it does. Unit tests are for testing the interface of your code, not the internals

Comment: Thanks for your answer Phil (3 years later, sorry).